# Angular 2 Break Into a new row

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2

Im looking to build a grid of items that breaks every 3rd and splits into a new row of another 3 cols.. I cant seems to figure out a way to do this intuitively with Ionic 2/Angular 2.

In PHP I would solve this problem using something like the following

```
    <?php 


    echo '<div class="open-block">';
    $i = 0

    while()....

    if($i % 3 === 0){
        echo '</div><div class="open-block">';
    }


    endwhile;

    echo '</div>';
```

unfortunately angular 2 wont allow me to do an ngIf to close a div. Has anyone got any neat tricks for solving this ?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need this kind of thing?

Comment: I want do display members pictures in an app gallery so that they can click on them to delete them. Im using Ionic 2

Answer (score 0):

Well this is the fastest way to do this on ionic 2.

Template:

```
<ion-grid>
  <ion-row *ngFor="let row of grid">
      <ion-col width-33 *ngFor="let image of row">
          <ion-img [src]="image.url">
       </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

Component:

```
  grid: Array; 

  loadGallery() {
     let rowsCount = Math.ceil(this.images.length / 3);
     grid = Array(rowsCount);

     for(let i = 0; i < rowsCount; i++) {
        grid[i] = this.getImages(i, 3);
     }
  }

  getImages(fromIndex:number, amount: number): Array {
    if ((fromIndex + amount) >= this.images.length)
       return this.image.slice(fromIndex, this.images.length - 1);
    return this.image.slice(fromIndex, amount);
  }
```

Just run the `loadGallery()` function when you fill the `this.images` (this is just a fancy name for the array where you will put the images).

I hope it helps.

Source: http://blog.ionic.io/layout-the-cool-way-using-the-ionic-2-grid-component

Comment: Cheers, I had come across this but It didnt really factor well into my existing code so i went with a css only approach using flexbox .member-group {
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

Comment: @REPTILE I am curious to know why it didn't fit in your existing code. The solution with flexbox is the best one because you don't need to worry about the amount of items that will fit on the screen, but your question was very specific, you wanted 3 items peer row.